# Java If statement won't work properly?

Tags: java

Using pIRCBot.

```
Class: pIRC.java
protected void onJoin(String channeljoined, String sender, String login, String hostname) {
    Bukkit.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "Channel joined: " + channeljoined + ". IRC channel: " + IRC.channel + "." );
    if(channeljoined == IRC.channel)
    {
        Bukkit.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "--");
        for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&',"&c[IRC]&e " + sender + "&f has joined the IRC channel."));
        }
    }
}
```

My IRC class has this:

```
Class: IRC.java
public static String channel;
```

Then I change the channel to a String got from a config file:

```
Class: IRC.java
channel = this.getConfig().getString("publicchannel");
```

And now whenever a user joins the IRC channel it prints:

`[11:03:53 INFO]: Channel joined: #MoMoMC. IRC channel: #MoMoMC.`

But it won't proceed to the next if statement. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: use equals not ==

Comment: as both are String try with equals methods. hope that will work.

Comment: `if` statements, if they execute, execute once and only once.  For repeated execution, you need some sort of loop (`do`, `while`, or `for`).  But your bigger problem is that you are trying to compare strings using `==`.  Don't do that.  Use `String#equals` instead (and read the duplicate link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing String with ==, Always comare String with .equals method.
String is a class. The function checks the actual contents of the string, the == operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal. 
Please change condition like this:

```
if(channeljoined.equals(IRC.channel))
```